# valueChangeListener method is called on selectOneMenu even though I have not changed the value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have the following problem. When I click the button "Enviar", this calls another method that is associated to a selectOneMenu (in the attribute
valueChangeListener called "validarSelect"), and later, calls the method that this button has associated in the attribute actionListener called "validarBoton".
I wonder, why this happens. I expect the `valueChangeListener` to be not called since I have not changed the dropdown.

This is my page JSF:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Enviar..." id="validar" actionListener="#{Domiciliacion.validarBoton}"/>
            <h:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{Domiciliacion.validarSelect}"
                             binding="#{Domiciliacion.selectCombo}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{Domiciliacion.lista}"/>
                <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="@this"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And this, is the ManagedBean:

```
package domiciliaciontest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "Domiciliacion")
@ViewScoped

public class MB0001 {


private HtmlSelectOneMenu selectCombo;
private List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

public MB0001() {
    super();
    System.out.println("Entro al constructor...");
    lista.add("Caracas");
    lista.add("Bogota");
    lista.add("Santiago");
}


public void validarBoton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    System.out.println("Entro a validarBoton...");
    // Add event code here...
}

public void validarSelect(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    // Add event code here...
    System.out.println("Entro a validarSelect...");
}

public void setSelectCombo(HtmlSelectOneMenu selectCombo) {
    this.selectCombo = selectCombo;
}

public HtmlSelectOneMenu getSelectCombo() {
    return selectCombo;
}

public void setLista(List<String> lista) {
    this.lista = lista;
}

public List<String> getLista() {
    return lista;
}
}
```

this is the output when I click the button "Enviar":

- Entro a validarSelect...
- Entro a validarBoton...

Comment: That's specified behaviour. What's your question/problem? Is that not what you want? Elaborate the concrete functional requirement in detail then. By the way, you do not want to use `binding` this way, I'd entirely remove it, but that's another problem.

Comment: Hi BalusC, but shouldn't it just call the actionListener when I click on the button?

Comment: since I'm not changing the value of the h:selectOnMenu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `valueChangeListener` method will be invoked when the submitted value is different from the initial value, regardless of whether you have changed it *yourself* or not. So, if the currently submitted value (which is `"Caracas"` in your case) is different from the initial value (which is `null` in your case), then the `valueChangeListener` method will be invoked.

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)
- [Best way to add a "nothing selected" option to a selectOneMenu in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, seeing this in combination with `binding` attribute gives me the impression that you're trying to achieve something which you've read in an article or answer targeted on JSF 1.x. This is namely recognizeable as part of a hack to populate child dropdowns in JSF 1.x. You do *not* need this approach for JSF 2.x. Further, your method names with "validar" ("validate") are misleading. Don't you *actually* need a fullworthy `Validator`? But as said, that's a different problem.

#### See also:

- [Make multiple dependent / cascading selectOneMenu dropdown lists in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378099/make-multiple-dependent-cascading-selectonemenu-dropdown-lists-in-jsf)

Comment: mmm Ok, and how i should changed the value of SelectOneMenu to initialize ? is said, of null by other personalized value ? Thank you !!!

Comment: Just set the component's `value` to the desired value. If you replace `binding="#{Domiciliacion.selectCombo}"` by `value="#{Domiciliacion.selectCombo}"` with `private String selectCombo;` then just add the line `selectCombo = "Caracas";` to the bean's constructor.

Comment: As said, just set the component's `value` to the desired value. Go back through your basic JSF book/tutorial (or go find/buy one if you don't already have one).