# JSF Populate A SINGLE (Not Multiple) Dropdown Based on Radio Button Selection

Tags: jsf

I am going through the Oracle tutorials while taking a class for Java EE and I wanted to make a dropdown menu that populates based on which radio button is selected.

To further clarify as this was marked as duplicate and it is not. I have a  radio button and a dropdown menu. I want my dropdown menu to populate with data from one of four arrays in my backing bean. If the selection of the radio button changes, I want the data in the dropdown to change based on what was selected in the radio selection.

Just to be clear, this is not for an assignment.

A snippet of some of the code I have is what you see below.

This code renders the dropdown with the string array that I have in my bean for "makeHonda". It automatically renders that whether or not it is selected. I would like it to update the dropdown with car models based on which radio button is clicked.

I have looked at several different questions here and also googled as well as looking through the Oracle tutorial and I just haven't found what I am looking for. Most questions I have seen seem to have their own context and are different than what I am trying to do.

These are in my bean

```
private String[] carMake = {"Honda", "Nissan", "Suzuki", "Toyota"};
private String[] makeHonda = {"Civic", "NSX"};
private String[] makeNissan = {"Fairlady 420Z", "Sylvia S13"};
private String[] makeSuzuki = {"Cappuccino", "Jimny"};
private String[] makeToyota = {"Altezza RS200", "Crown"};
private String makeSelection;
private String carModels;
```

This stuff is in the xhtml file

```
<label>Favorite Car Maker: </label>
<h:selectOneRadio id="carMake" value="#{controller.makeSelection}" required="true" label="Action">
    <f:selectItems value="#{controller.carMake}"/>
    <f:ajax render="carModels" />
</h:selectOneRadio>

<!-- Car Models Drop Down Appears After Car Selection -->
<label>Favorite Car Model: </label>
<h:selectOneMenu id="carModels" value="#{controller.carModels}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{controller.makeHonda}" rendered="#{controller.makeSelection eq 'Honda'}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question with the help of another post that I will list at the end.

These are the changes that I made to my bean.

```
private String selectedMake;
private String[] availableModels;
private String[] carMakes = {"Honda", "Nissan", "Suzuki", "Toyota"};
private String[] makeHonda = {"Civic", "NSX"};
private String[] makeNissan = {"Fairlady 420Z", "Sylvia S13"};
private String[] makeSuzuki = {"Cappuccino", "Jimny"};
private String[] makeToyota = {"Altezza RS200", "Crown"};

public void changeModels(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    if ("Honda".equals(selectedMake)) {
        availableModels = makeHonda;
    }
    if ("Nissan".equals(selectedMake)) {
        availableModels = makeNissan;
    }
    if ("Suzuki".equals(selectedMake)) {
        availableModels = makeSuzuki;
    }
    if ("Toyota".equals(selectedMake)) {
        availableModels = makeToyota;
    }
}
```

This is the changes that I made to my xhtml file.

```
<!-- Selection for Favorite Car Maker -->
        <p></p>
        <label>Favorite Car Maker: </label>
        <h:selectOneRadio id="carMake" value="#{controller.selectedMake}" required="true" label="Action">
            <f:selectItems value="#{controller.carMakes}"/>
            <f:ajax listener="#{controller.changeModels}" render="carModels" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>

        <!-- Car Models Drop Down Appears After Car Selection -->
        <label>Favorite Car Model: </label>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="carModels" value="#{controller.selectedMake}">
            <f:selectItem value="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select --" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{controller.availableModels}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

The post that I was linked to before was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378099/make-multiple-dependent-cascading-selectonemenu-dropdown-lists-in-jsf).

In that post the user asks how to make multiple selectonemenu lists stemming from other selectonemenu lists. The answer there lead me to solving it, however it was a bit different than what I actually did.

Comment: What was so different that it was not a duplicate (which it in my opinion is)

Comment: He was creating a dropdown from one dropdown, then another dropdown then another dropdown in succession. Multiple dropdown boxes, not a single dropdown box that changes the data inside of it based off of a radio button. Also im not entirely sure what he was using `@EJB
    private SomeService someService;` for but my code does not use that. So my question and the way I solved it are different.

Comment: The concept does not differ if you have/use one or many related components. So that part does not really play a role. The `@EJB` might be different, but that is not the most relevant part, but great it works now... cheers