# Ajax Conditional update on Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to do a conditional update with Ajax. I have two calendar components and the code is as follows

Calendar component 1 (workDate)

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{lbl.WorkDate}" for="workDate" rendered="#{!userManager.customerUser}"/>
<p:calendar id="workDate" value="#{jobs_Builder.selected.workDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" rendered="#{!userManager.customerUser}" mindate="Date()">
      <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="requestedDeliveryDate" />
</p:calendar>
```

Calendar component 2(requestedDeliveryDate)

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{lbl.RequestedDeliveryDate}" for="requestedDeliveryDate" rendered="#{!userManager.customerUser}"/>
<p:calendar id="requestedDeliveryDate" value="#{jobs_Builder.selected.requestedDeliveryDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" rendered="#{!userManager.customerUser}" mindate="#{jobs_Builder.selected.workDate}"/>
```

The behavior is whenever the date is set in `wordkdate`, the `requestedDeliveryDate` is reset, but what I want is to get that reset only if the `requestedDeliveryDate` is earlier than the `workDate`.

Is this something which I can do?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378099/make-multiple-dependent-cascading-selection-components-in-jsf This is the same principle.

Comment: Yes in your `dateSelect` event don't use `update` call a Java `listener` method and in that method you can check the dates and if the date meets your requirement then you can choose to update the other calendar from the server side with `PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("requestedDeliveryDate");`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Melloware. Works like a charm

Comment: OK I posted it as the answer if you don't mind selecting it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your `dateSelect` event not to `update` anything but use a Java listener instead like..

```xml
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{controller.onDateSelect}" />
```

2. In your Java method check for your two dates and if your condition is met update the UI component from this method.

```java
public void onDateSelect() {
    if (date1 > date2) {
        // update other calendar
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("requestedDeliveryDate");
    }
}
```